# What does \+ do in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm studying this code, and there is a  + in the color function which I have no idea what it does. I'm very confused by this and I'm basically stuck on this because I can't understand what it does.

```
/* prolog  tutorial 2.9 Map coloring redux */
adjacent(X,Y,Map) :-  member([X,Y],Map) ; member([Y,X],Map). 
find_regions([],R,R). 
find_regions([[X,Y]|S], R,A) :- 
 (member(X,R) ->  
  (member(Y,R) -> find_regions(S,R,A) ; find_regions(S,[Y|R],A)) ; 
    (member(Y,R) -> find_regions(S,[X|R],A) ; find_regions(S,[X,Y|R],A) ) ). 

color(Map,Colors,Coloring) :-
    find_regions(Map,[],Regions), 
    color_all(Regions,Colors,Coloring), 
    \+ conflict(Map,Coloring). 
color_all([R|Rs],Colors,[[R,C]|A]) :- 
    member(C,Colors), 
    color_all(Rs,Colors,A). 
color_all([],_,[]). 


conflict(Map,Coloring) :- 
    member([R1,C],Coloring), 
    member([R2,C],Coloring), 
    adjacent(R1,R2,Map). 

map1([[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4],[4,5]] ).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a negation, see [here](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html#negation) for a  detailed explanation with examples. You can basically just read it as equivalent to 'not', or more accurately, 'not provable'.

Comment: So could you explain to me more exactly what it does on that piece of code? This code is supposed to solve the graph coloring problem, where no 2 adjacent nodes can have the same color. So what colors does, is first it gets a list of the nodes, then it assigns a color to each one making sure there isn't a conflict between colors. 

What is the purpose of /+ conflict on this code then?

Comment: `conflict(Map,Coloring)` is **true** if there is a conflict in the coloring. You don't want conflicts, so `color()` needs `conflict()` to fail. As you said, it makes sure there isn't a conflict. If you left out the `\+`, it would make sure there **is** a conflict.

Comment: So basically it means the code will only resolve if coloring is not(true) hence false?

I may be confused here but I think there's iterations happening but I can't see where and this is confusing me.

Comment: Yes that is right. If there is a conflict, `\+ conflict(Map, Coloring)` will fail, and Prolog will backtrack and try to assign a different coloring.

Answer (score 2):

"In standard Prolog the operator  +  means negation as failure"

There ist a good Tutorial found [here](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse45).